# How to efficiently do one-to-many collision checks?

Tags: collision-detection, javascript, node.js

Scenario: 4 players, each can have from 1 to 100 pawns.

I want to be able to efficiently check if Player 1's pawns collides with Player 2, 3, and 4.

Currently I have an AABB check, done first on Player 1's side where it checks against Player 2's pawns. Now I realized I have to do this for the rest of the players.

This is done on a NodeJS server. If a collision is detected, it sends a message to each player, which in turn kills the pawn in question

````js
// aabbCheck
var aabbCheck = function (aabb1, aabb2) {
    if (aabb1.x + aabb1.w > aabb2.x &&
        aabb1.x < aabb2.x + aabb2.w &&
        aabb1.y + aabb1.h > aabb2.y &&
        aabb1.y < aabb2.y + aabb2.h) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
// make the pawns move based on the angle the player targets
var marchPawn = function (pawn) {
    var speed = 90;
    pawn.aabb.x += speed * (Math.cos(pawn.angle) * (Date.now() - pawn.spawnTime) * 0.001);
    pawn.aabb.y += speed * (Math.sin(pawn.angle) * (Date.now() - pawn.spawnTime) * 0.001);
    pawn.spawnTime = Date.now();
};
// check if pawn collides with another entity
var checkPawnCollision = function (pawn, other) {
    var aabb1 = {};
    aabb1.x = pawn.aabb.x;
    aabb1.y = pawn.aabb.y;
    aabb1.w = pawn.aabb.w;
    aabb1.h = pawn.aabb.h;

    var aabb2 = {};
    aabb2.x = other.aabb.x;
    aabb2.y = other.aabb.y;
    aabb2.w = other.aabb.w;
    aabb2.h = other.aabb.h;

    if (aabbCheck(aabb1, aabb2)) {
        // console.log('pawn collides with other');
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};

var playerPawn = {
    player1: [],
    player2: [],
    player3: [],
    player4: []
};

// Check if player 1 have pawns on the field
if (playerPawn.player1.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < playerPawn.player1.length; i++) {
        var pawn = playerPawn.player1[i];
        if (pawn) {
            // make the pawn move
            marchPawn(pawn);

            // Check if player 1 pawn collides with player 2 pawn
            if (playerPawn.player2.length > 0) {
                for (var j = 0; j < playerPawn.player2.length; j++) {
                    var p2pawn = playerPawn.player2[j];
                    if (p2pawn) {
                        if (checkPawnCollision(pawn, p2pawn)) {
                            // console.log('Pawn Collision');
                            playerPawn.player1.splice(i, 1);
                            playerPawn.player2.splice(j, 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
// NOT YET DONE
// Check if player 2 have pawns on the field
if (playerPawn.player2.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < playerPawn.player2.length; i++) {
        var pawn = playerPawn.player2[i];
        if (pawn) {
            marchPawn(pawn);
        }
    }
}
// NOT YET DONE
// Check if player 3 have pawns on the field
if (playerPawn.player3.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < playerPawn.player3.length; i++) {
        var pawn = playerPawn.player3[i];
        if (pawn) {
            marchPawn(pawn);
        }
    }
}
// NOT YET DONE
// Check if player 4 have pawns on the field
if (playerPawn.player4.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < playerPawn.player4.length; i++) {
        var pawn = playerPawn.player4[i];
        if (pawn) {
            marchPawn(pawn);
        }
    }
}

```
````

Comment: What makes you believe that your implementation is not efficient enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a big error in your code that will have you pull you hair until you're bald.

When you `playerPawn.player1.splice(i, 1);` you effectively change the size of the array, which is not bad per se, but the objects that were *after* this index are shifted *and* you still increment the index, so you'll effectively skip the object that was right after the one you just removed. To fix this, increment your index (i or j) *only* if no item was removed. FWIW, changing an array like this in a loop is typically seen as inefficient (because of all the shifts).

I think there might be a couple of game design issues too, based on the algorithm that you currently use. I'm assuming that all four players play against each other, and no player should be favoured.

1. If you call `marchPawn(pawn);`, then check right away for collisions, some pawns will not have the chance to move, so the concept of "chase" will never happen in your game (P1 pawn moved one step toward x+, and P2 pawn moved at the same time, in the same direction).
2. If you start to check for collisions between Player1 pawns and Player2 pawns, and remove them right away, there are situations that a Player1 pawn could hit a Player2 pawn *and* a Player3 pawn during the same frame. That's okay for P1 and P2, but P3 is the winner here because the algorithm did not even check for the collision with their pawn.

Here is a piece of pseudocode that tries to get around these issues.

```
pawnArrays[4][100] // four players, each 100 pawns

// Move everyone first; this makes sure that all the Pawns have a chance to move 
// every frame, makes "chase" possible.
for ( p : [0..3] )
{
  for( pPawnIndex : [0..pawnArrays[p].length-1] )
    marchPawn(pawnArrays[p][pPawnIndex]);
}

// Then check for collisions
for ( pA : [0..2] )
{
  for( pB : [pA + 1..3] )
  {  
    for( pApawnIndex : [0..pawnArrays[pA].length-1 )
    {
      for( pBpawnIndex : [0..pawnArrays[pB].length-1 )
      {
        // Note that we do check collisions even with those that are "dead"
        // to allow "three way" collisions. 
        if ( checkPawnCollision(pawnArrays[pA][pApawnIndex], pawnArrays[pB][pBpawnIndex]) )
        {
          pawnArrays[pA][pApawnIndex].dead = true
          pawnArrays[pB][pBpawnIndex].dead = true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Then react to collisions
for ( p : [0..3] )
{
  // We "push" via copy all the "dead" objects at the end of the array. We "swap" a
  // dead pawn from the beginning of the array with a pawn from the end of the 
  // array, so at the end, all the dead ones are at the end, and we can easily
  // splice them all at once. This avoid multiple array shifts.
  // Note that this will shuffle the order of the Pawns in the arrays, but AFAIK,
  // it does not appear to be an issue for your situation. 
  goodIndex = 0
  placeBadIndex = pawnArrays[p].length
  while( goodIndex != placeBadIndex )
  {
    if ( pawnArrays[p][goodIndex].dead )
    {
      temp = pawnArrays[p][goodIndex]
      pawnArrays[p][goodIndex] = pawnArrays[p][placeBadIndex-1]
      pawnArrays[p][placeBadIndex-1] = temp
      --placeBadIndex
    }
    else
    {
      ++goodIndex
    }
  }
  
  // then we delete them
  pawnArrays[p].splice(placeBadIndex)
}
```

Note that this algorithm here takes care of suggestion #3 from [the other answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/200242/40264). You could go ahead and improve this further once you profile your game and realize it's a bottle neck by using the other more generic suggestions provided in that answer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for [collision detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection)

It's a common problem with game engines: how to efficiently check if an object collides with the other(when there are hundreds of objects in the scene).

In your particular case (single shape, no triangles), here are some strategies:

1. **Exploiting temporal coherence:** Cache last collision result. If the two objects for checking did not move, just use the old result.
2. **Spatial partitioning:** If the two objects for checking are far away, they absolutely have no chance to collide, no need to check them. Spatial partitioning is a good way to do it. Basically, we need to divide the game scene into cells and create a manager of all cells. When an object is created/destroyed/moved, tell the manager the new position. For each object just check the objects only in the same cell and cells nearby. You can simply use an array, or an [octree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree).
3. **Same collision avoiding**: while Player 1 is already checked(with other players), no need to check Player 1 again when you check Player 2.